# Like button change with transition effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating like or thumbs up button and i want to add some **transition effect**, kinda like short `fade in fade out` effect on icon change, where on **click** icon will disappear or fadeout and then new icon will fade in and whole animation will be `0.6s-0.8s` top. Icons are `font-awesome icons`.

This is what i got so far https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/11/

HTML

```
<h3>This is post 1</h3>
<div class="like">0 <button class="like-button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button></div>

<h3>This is post 2</h3>
<div class="like">0 <button class="like-button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button></div>
```

CSS

```
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

button {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.like button {
    border: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('.like-button').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-thumbs-o-up').addClass('fa-thumbs-up');
  });
})
```

Comment: I think you should revise your question because what you're asking is not really clear.

Comment: I am not sure what is not clear about it?

Comment: You made some statements dude. The question, dude, where is the question?

Comment: The question is how to change this icon with fade animation or transition, i think this is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `promise().done()` to have the class changed after the fadeout is complete, and then fade in immediately after the class is changed.

```
$('.like-button').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $this = $(this).children('i');
        $this.fadeTo(600, 0).promise().done(function () {
            $this.removeClass('fa-thumbs-o-up').addClass('fa-thumbs-up').fadeTo(600,1);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: There may be a better way, as I'm not an expert.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

in css

```
.like-button i {
  transition:1s all ease;   
}
```